# Iterate two Vectors of same size different values with one ForEach statment in java

Tags: java, vector, foreach

Is it possible to use a single

```
Vector vector1 = new Vector();
Vector vector2 = new Vector();
Map map = new HashMap();
for(String key:vector1&&String value:vector2)
{
 map.put(key,value);
}
```

or something similar.I am trying to poulate a map with these two vectors.I tried the above  for each statement but it gave me a syntax error.
Any help.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't work.

this:

```
for(String key:vector1){
}
```

is a shortcut for this:

```
for(Iterator<String> it = vector1.iterator();it.hasNext();){
    String key = it.next();
}
```

And it works with one iterator only.

Here's some code that gets close to what you want:

```
// don't use vector, it's ancient and unofficially deprecated
final List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();

//...
// add keys and values here


final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(
    Iterator<String> it1 = keyList.iterator(), it2 = valueList.iterator();
    // this works even if the lists have different sizes
    it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext();){

    map.put(it1.next(), it2.next());

}
```

I also took the liberty to address some flaws in your code:

1. [Don't use Raw Types in new code](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/generics.pdf) (use generics)
2. Don't use `Vector`, `Hashtable` or `Enumeration`, use `ArrayList<E>`, `HashMap<K,V>`, `Iterator<E>` (respectively) instead. Many questions here cover this, [including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453684/use-hashtable-vector-or-hashmap-or-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: I understand Vector is performance degrader but inside JTable they are still using Vector.Is there any way to avoid using Vector in that case?

Comment: @Harish oh god, no. I guess you are stuck with vector in that case. I'm amazed they never changed that API.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the old style?

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector1.size() && i < vector2.size(); i++) { 
  map.put(vector1.get(i), vector2.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its *not* allowed           You can however use this.

```
        Vector<String> vector1 = new Vector();
        Vector<String> vector2 = new Vector();
        Map <String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int index = 0 ; index < vector1.size() ; index ++ )      //vector1 & vector are of same length
        {
            map.put(vector1.elementAt(index), vector2.elementAt(index));
        }
```

Comment: `Map <String,String> map = new HashMap<>();` This syntax won't work before JDK 1.7

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing like that. You'll have to use two loops.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such construct but you could do something like :

```
Iterator i1 = vector1.iterator();
Iterator i2 = vector2.iterator();

while (i1.hasNext() ) {
   map.put(i1.next(),i2.next());
}
```

Assuming the same size for both vectors.

Answer (score 1):

No, that doesn't work. You can get that effect like this:

```
Iterator<String> i1 = v1.iterator();
Iterator<String> i2 = v2.iterator();
while (i1.hasNext()) {
  map.put(i1.next(), i2.next();
}
assert !i2.hasNext();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no parallel `for` statement, but you can use `Iterator`s:

```
Vector vector1 = new Vector();
// ...populate vector1...
Vector vector2 = new Vector();
// ...populate vector2...
Map map = new HashMap();
Iterator it1, it2;
it1 = vector1.iterator();
it2 = vector2.iterator();
while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext())
{
    map.put(it1.next(), it2.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for-each loop behind the scene is converted to typical old fashion iterator so

```
 for(String item : items){
  ...
 }
```

Are converted by the compiler into

```
Iterator iItems = items.iterator()
while(iItems.hasNext()){
    String item = iItems.next();
     ...
}
```

So you could do sth like that:

```
Iterator iVector2 = vector2.iterator();
for(String item1: vector1){
  String item2 = iVector2.next();
  ....
}
```