# What is the Best Way to Store some data in Java? (Array vs ArrayList)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, store

So currently, I am extracting two different attributes from an XML file in java that (for my project) are related to each other and just printing them out to the console. However, I want to be able to store these in a way in which referencing one value will retrieve it's corresponding counterpart. For example:

```
Id: rId11 & Target: image3
Id: rId10 & Target: image2
Id: rId9 & Target: image1
```

With those 3 values, I'd want a way to store each line, but when I reference "rId" I could get it's corresponding "Target" value. I was thinking about using either an array or an arrayList, but I'm not really sure which would be better for my purposes or how exactly I would go about referencing only one value and getting the other. Could anyone offer me some advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your keys are unique, use a [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

```
Map<String, String> mak = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("rId11","image3");
map.put("rId10","image2");
map.put("rId9","image1");
```

**Reference:**

- [Java Tutorial > The Map
  Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Otherwise, create a custom Object that holds key and value and create a [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (or [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)???) of these.

```
public class Entry {
    private final String id;
    private final String value;
    public Entry(String id, String value) {
        this.id = id; this.value = value;
    }
    public String getId() { return id; }
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    // also implement equals() and hashCode(), please
}

List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
entries.add(new Entry("rId11","image3"));
```

**Reference:**

- [Java Tutorial > The List Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)
- [Java Tutorial > The Set Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I decided to go with your HashMap answer but with a few slight modifications for what I'm doing specifically. Fairly new to Java, so I didn't even consider mapping until you mentioned it. Also thanks to everyone else who contributed for your input. :)

Comment: @This 0ne Pr0grammer: you're welcome. If you're new to Java, you should work yourself through the Java Tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial and read Effective Java (2nd Ed) by Josh Bloch.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), with the Id ad the key and the Target as the value.  Note that Map is an interface and thus defines behavior only.  You will need to pick a specific implementation, such as HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

You're being a bit ambiguous about what you want.  If you want to lookup a value based on a given key, then store the pairs in a [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (faster) or [Hashtable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) (slower but thread-safe).

Primitive arrays (and more advanced [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)-based collections such and [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [Vector](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)) don't work with name-value pairs out of the box.  They are simply, well... lists.  Primitive arrays can offer a bit more performance, since you avoid creating objects, but the more advanced List-type collections can be safer and more flexible.

Still, it sounds (?) like you want a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) type collection rather [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) type one.

**UPDATE**:  By the way, if you use a Map then you can still work with a list of all your "rId" values.  It will be a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) datatype actually, but that's just a special cousin of List that doesn't allow duplicates:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("rId11","image3");
// ... additional put's for the other values

Set<String> myRids = myMap.keySet();
for(String rId : myRids) {
   // do whatever you want with each rId one-by-one, etc
   // You could also use "myRids.iterator()" to work with an Iterator instead
}
```

Comment: Please don't recommend Vector and Hashtable. They should have been deprecated years ago. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453684/use-hashtable-vector-or-hashmap-or-arraylist-in-java) or one of the [many other related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bhashtable+%2Bvector+%2Bdeprecated) for more info.

Comment: Oh give me a break.  Yeah, I'm 99.999% sure that this guy isn't writing a multi-threaded app.  Yeah, even in my own multi-threaded development, I haven't used a Vector or Hashtable since around 2002.  However, it's a common source of confusion for newbies, and they'll never REALLY take it out of the standard library... so I think it's useful to at least explain to newbies what those redundant-looking types were there for.

Comment: To clarify for the original question asker... it's better to use HashMap rather than Hashtable, and ArrayList rather than Vector.  Those latter types provide some arcane levels of protection, but it isn't useful to most development and it comes with a serious performance penalty.

Answer (score 2):

I think a java.util.HashMap would be better suited for this requirement especially if sorting is not required.

```
// not sure what types these are but this would work better
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
m.put("rId11", "image3");
String other = m.get("rId11");
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, you want to be able to do look for something like "rId10" and get the value "image2" (and only that).

If that is the case,I think the best (in terms of speed) and easiest solution will be a hash table (java.util.Hashtable) - be careful to use Java Generics as well (after Java 1.5). Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table also.

Comment: Please don't recommend Hashtable. It should have been deprecated years ago. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453684/use-hashtable-vector-or-hashmap-or-arraylist-in-java) or one of the [many other related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bhashtable+%2Bvector+%2Bdeprecated) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If the "keys" to your target values will be unique and only ever have one target mapped to them, then I would recommend using java.util.HashMap instead. You can retrieve any target value by passing in the key. Plus you can Iterate over HashMap like you could an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Item {
    private String id;
    private String target;

    public Item(String id, String target) {
        this.id = id;
        this.target = target;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getTarget() {
        return this.target;
    }
}

 List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
 // or
 Map<String, Item> itemsIndexedById = new HashMap<String, Item>();
 // depending on your use-case
```

Read [the Java tutorial about collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is useful if you need to add elements to it dynamically